# Не получается написать wall.post запрос vk api ( error_code : 3 )

Tags: vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь написать API запрос для создания записи на странице вк ( моей ). Запрос выглядит следующим образом: **api.vk.com/method/wall.post?message=asfsafasf&access_token=2a2d535404bccdb42f5361410776d313b008g807bb6327a347bzf678e8ab731a16513157ee603302e7026&v=5.131**

В ответ на этот запрос мне кидает ошибку: **{"error":{"error_code":3,"error_msg":"Unknown method passed","request_params":[{"key":"message","value":"asfsafasf"},{"key":"v","value":"5.131"},{"key":"method","value":"wall.post"},{"key":"oauth","value":"1"}]}}**

Как я понял - эта ошибка связана с неправильным названием метода, но я делал всё по документации и вроде бы все должно работать. Api запрос пытаюсь вызвать из браузерной строки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: скорее всего запрос выглядит совершенно не так, как вы его сюда скопировали. Напишите код в вопрос...сравним......в целом да, такого метода нет...скорее всего где-то в коде опечатка

Comment: я пробую вызвать этот запрос через браузерную строку, чтобы вручную проверить работает он или нет

Answer (score 0):

А где owner_id?

```
GroupID = set->value("General/GroupID").toString();
VKToken = set->value("General/VKToken").toString();
QString url = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=-" + GroupID + "&message=" + strk + "&attachments=" + attach + "&access_token=" + VKToken + "&v=5.131";

QObject::connect(managerVK, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(onResultVK(QNetworkReply*))); //отправляем данные и получаем ответ от вк успешно или ошибка
managerVK->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
```

У меня уже неколько лет такая конструкция работает.