# Не получается написать wall.post запрос vk api

Tags: vkontakte-api

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой [Не получается написать wall.post запрос vk api ( error_code : 3 )](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1398665/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-wall-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-vk-api-error-code-3/1452041?noredirect=1#comment2593678_1452041). Свой токен проверил на других запросах - сообщения отправляет. Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Решено. У токена не хватало прав доступа.